# Dask.dataframe.merge on indices unexpectedly slow

Tags: python, dataframe, dask-dataframe

**Problem**:  When attempting to merge two Dask dataframes on indices, I am seeing unexpectedly slow performance.  I would expect the merge to be "cleverly parallelized," since I am merging on indices.  Each DF is only ~150K rows x 2 columns; however, the merge takes 2+ minutes and I do not see parallelization occurring.

**Ask**: How to improve performance?

**Code Snippet**:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

b_size = 10*1024*1024
filename = 'df1.csv'
multiple_fns = 'df2/*'
output_fn = 'output.csv'

df1 = dd.read_csv(filename, block_size=b_size, dtype={'var1': np.float64, 'var2': np.uint64})
df1 = df1.set_index('var1')

df2 = dd.read_csv(multiple_fns, block_size=b_size, dtype={'var1': np.float64, 'var3': np.uint64})
df2 = df2.set_index('var1')

df1 = df1.merge(right=df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df.to_csv(output_fn, single_file=True, header=True, index=False)
```

**Dask Dashboard Screenshot**:
[Dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mfpe.png)

Comment: Did you have a look at the dask dashboard to figure out what it's doing?

Comment: I did not - rather new to Dask. I am running this fully on a local machine (not using Dask distributed).

Comment: try `from dask.distributed import Client`, `client = Client(dashboard_address='127.0.0.1:41012', n_workers=10)` and `
client`, then you can navigate to that address in your browser and see the dashboard. Doesn't matter whether it's a single machine or distributed. Run this before anything else. Restart kernel before that.

Comment: Posted screenshot in original description. join-indexed-getitem is taking up the lion-share of processing time.

Comment: @mcsoini - I am now seeing different behavior despite not changing code.  My local machine is not leveraging the additional processes and I cannot load the Dask dashboard. I'm at a loss.